# Firebase query for two values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement locational based query in Firebase without GeoFire (Since the last update was 6 months ago it seems deprecated)

Anyhow, I can't figure this out.

It's not firing the listener.
When there's not starting at or ending at it works.

Query looks like so: (Just testing with Latitude)

```
// Testing, only doing longtude atm.
        geoFlamesFIRReference
            .queryStarting(atValue: coordinates!.longitude - radius, childKey: "longtitude")
            .queryEnding(atValue: coordinates!.longitude + radius, childKey: "longtitude")
            .queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(Constants.LIMIT_OF_FLAMES_ON_MAP))
            .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                print("New location?")
            })
```

Then example of some of my data:

[image: Firebase geo example not working]

Comment: GeoFire is not deprecated. It works fine, so hasn't needed updating in a while.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong syntax for querying:

```
geoFlamesFIRReference
    .queryOrder(byChild: "longtitude")
    .queryStarting(atValue: coordinates!.longitude - radius)
    .queryEnding(atValue: coordinates!.longitude + radius)
```

Note that you will run into problems when you also want to filter by latitude, as [Firebase queries can only contain a single `orderBy` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase).

GeoFire uses [geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) to work around this limitation. So if you're intent on not using that library, you will have to read up on those.